# IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'field' cannot be null") even though null=True

Tags: python, django, validation, null

I'm getting an Integrity error in Django and I'm struggling to understand why. When I try to save my formset I get the error

> IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'field' cannot be null"

But in my models I've allowed the field to be null, so I don't understand why this error is being raised?

```
class Time(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    timesheet_id = models.ForeignKey(TimeSheet, null=True, related_name="time_set")
    field = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True, editable=False)
    def __unicode__ (self):
        return self.description or u''
```

Here's my traceback:

```
Internal Server Error: /app/2/timesheet/week/submit/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/username/Documents/code/project/app/views.py", line 394, in my_view
    time_formset.save()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 645, in save
    return self.save_existing_objects(commit) + self.save_new_objects(commit)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 775, in save_new_objects
    self.new_objects.append(self.save_new(form, commit=commit))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 913, in save_new
    obj.save()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 700, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 728, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 812, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 851, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 122, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1039, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1060, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 117, in execute
    six.reraise(utils.IntegrityError, utils.IntegrityError(*tuple(e.args)), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 112, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 205, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'field' cannot be null")
```

Why am I getting this if I've allowed the field to be null in the model?

Here's the view being executed, also "is valid" is printing to the console after I run timeformset.is_valid()... so I'm even more confused...

```
def my_view(request, timesheet_id):
    timesheets = TimeSheet.objects.get(pk=timesheet_id)
    TimeFormSet = inlineformset_factory(TimeSheet, Time, form=TimeForm, extra=1, can_delete=True, formset=CustomInlineFormSet)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        time_formset = TimeFormSet(request.POST, instance=timesheets)
        if time_formset.is_valid(): 
            #This prints to the console         
            print "is validating"
            time_formset.save()
        else:
            print "not validating"
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("app:next_view"))
```

Help!

(I also just did a pull from Git and ran migrations again on another computer, not sure if this is relevant)

Comment: Where is `add_row`?

Comment: Bad edit I'll change it now @jordanm

Comment: @RuthYoung did you make this change recently ? If so, you will need to migrate it first.

Comment: @algrebe Yes it was the most recent thing I did. I have migrated and it said no migrations to apply